# Creating aggregate node via XSLT with kicker

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion

I don't think well in xsl, so I'm having trouble comprehending how to handle this.  I need to make an aggregate of the quantity, but grouped by the id in the attribute in the parent node.  I'm thinking this should be a horribly simple recursion template, but I'm having trouble pumping it out

This input xml looks like this:

```
<foo>
  <lines>
    <line line_id="10000">
      <qty>10</qty>
    </line>
    <line line_id="10000">
      <qty>4</qty>
    </line>
    <line line_id="10000">
      <qty>12</qty>
    </line>
    <line line_id="20000">
      <qty>1</qty>
    </line>
    <line line_id="30000">
      <qty>4</qty>
    </line>
    <line line_id="30000">
      <qty>6</qty>
    </line>
  </lines>
  <lines>
    <line line_id="10000">
      <qty>4</qty>
    </line>
  </lines>
</foo>
```

The output should be:

```
<newfoo>
  <items>
    <item>
      <item_id>10000</item_id>
      <quantity>26</quantity>
    </item>
    <item>
      <item_id>20000</item_id>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
    </item>
    <item>
      <item_id>30000</item_id>
      <quantity>10</quantity>
    </item>
  </items>
  <items>
    <item>
      <item_id>10000</item_id>
      <quantity>4</quantity>
    </item>
  </items>
</newfoo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved in XSLT1.0 by using a method called Muenchian Grouping.

Firstly, you define a key to look-up the **line** elements for a given **lines** element using the **line_id** attribute as the key. So, for a given lines element and line_id attribute, all matching **line** elements will be returned. You will need a concatenated key for this.

```
<xsl:key name="id" 
   match="line" 
   use="concat(concat(generate-id(..), ','), @line_id)"/>
```

Next, you need to match the **line** elements which have the first occurrence of each distinct **line_id** attribute within the **lines** element. This is achieved as follows:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
  select="line[
    generate-id() = 
    generate-id(key('id',concat(concat(generate-id(..),','),@line_id))[1])]" />
```

i.e. Match **line** elements which happen to be the first elements in the list for the given key.

Then, you can get the total quantity, simply by summing all elements in the key

```
<xsl:value-of 
  select="sum(key('id', concat(concat(generate-id(..), ','), @line_id))/qty)"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="id" match="line" use="concat(concat(generate-id(..), ','), @line_id)"/>

   <xsl:template match="/foo">
      <newfoo>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="lines"/>
      </newfoo>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="lines">
      <items>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="line[generate-id() = generate-id(key('id', concat(concat(generate-id(..), ','), @line_id))[1])]"/>
      </items>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="line">
      <item>
         <item_id>
            <xsl:value-of select="@line_id"/>
         </item_id>
         <quantity>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('id', concat(concat(generate-id(..), ','), @line_id))/qty)"/>
         </quantity>
      </item>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML:

```
<foo>
   <lines>
      <line line_id="10000">
         <qty>10</qty>
      </line>
      <line line_id="10000">
         <qty>4</qty>
      </line>
      <line line_id="10000">
         <qty>12</qty>
      </line>
      <line line_id="20000">
         <qty>1</qty>
      </line>
      <line line_id="30000">
         <qty>4</qty>
      </line>
      <line line_id="30000">
         <qty>6</qty>
      </line>
   </lines>
   <lines>
      <line line_id="10000">
         <qty>4</qty>
      </line>
   </lines>
</foo>
```

The following XML is output:

```
<newfoo>
   <items>
      <item>
         <item_id>10000</item_id>
         <quantity>26</quantity>
      </item>
      <item>
         <item_id>20000</item_id>
         <quantity>1</quantity>
      </item>
      <item>
         <item_id>30000</item_id>
         <quantity>10</quantity>
      </item>
   </items>
   <items>
      <item>
         <item_id>10000</item_id>
         <quantity>4</quantity>
      </item>
   </items>
</newfoo>
```

Comment: That was a big help, but I ran into another issue I didn't think would be a problem, but I have another xml coming in that has multiple <lines> elements where the same id still needs aggregated separately.

I modified to source xml to display this.

Comment: @KupoMonkey I have amended the XSLT to do this. It now makes use of a concatenated key, but should do the trick.